# Align two LinearLayouts in Android not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to align two `LinearLayouts` inside a `RelativeLayout`. I want the first one to be aligned in the center of the `RelativeLayout`, and the second one to be aligned in bottom.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_descritpion"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/healthfile_title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <View 
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/text_userName"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#cdcdcd"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_style"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/home_email" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/text_userPassword"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#cdcdcd"
            android:background="@drawable/editbox_style"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/home_password" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="@string/home_login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't have an account already?" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I align hese `LinearLayouts` both inside the `RelativeLayout`, the first one keeps aligned in top...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `layout_centerInParent="true"` in the center layout and remove `android:gravity="center"` from `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="s" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_userName"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#cdcdcd"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_userPassword"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#cdcdcd"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an account already?" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have removed backgrounds and strings to preview in my pc.

Comment: Perfect solution! Neat and clean! Thanks :D

Comment: I tried this, but it pushed the second `LinearLayout` up. How did you prevent that?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke are you sure? Note that second layout has `layout_alignParentBottom=true`. It is okay in my A.Studio preview. Check your xml.

Comment: You won me for seconds :C

Comment: Yep, all I added was `layout_centerInParent="true"` to the first layout, and this is my [result](http://i.imgur.com/EJlmHmI.png)

Comment: You are right! I forget say that I have removed `android:gravity:"center"` from the `RelativeLayout`. Edited

Comment: Ah that does it. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an id for the first layout:

```
android:id="@+id/first"     // insert this code into the first layout
```

And you should move second layout below the first:

```
android:layout_below="@id/first" // write this code into the second layout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two attributes to your first `LinearLayout`

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I think the nicest way is @bigdestroyer's one... Thanks!